# What kind of silver NONstick pan is this? Even without grease or oil, sizzling pancake batter doesn't stick to it!

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Seasoned Advice post: [What kind of silver NONstick pan is this? Even without grease or oil, sizzling pancake batter doesn't stick to it!](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/122396/what-kind-of-silver-nonstick-pan-is-this-even-without-grease-or-oil-sizzling-p)

### [User Ecnerwal appears to need the original video to answer the question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/122433/101749). Can a moderator link to the original video without looking like spam?

#### I herewith swear that I am not affiliated or sponsored IN ANY WAY by that vlogger or BiliBili. I was not intending to spam or offend.

---

##### 1. I need a new NONstick pan! Please identify and characterize this one, in [this video starting from 0:03 seconds](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1vu411q7zF/?share_source=copy_web&t=3).

This pan looks sufficiently NONstick! Normally, [you must grease or oil  a pan](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/19186) before pouring in  pancake batter to forestall sticking. [But  Penny didn't grease or oil at all](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/94898), and her pancake didn't stick to the pan! She could flip her pancakes perfectly!

#### 2. Can anyone identify the materials in her flipper/spatula/turner? Is it silicone? Metal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your post, removing all links, and reopened. It shouldn't look so spam-like now. It was a very large edit, but the main question is not changed. Also, I made a single question out of it, we don't answer multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: Plus the link gave a lot of browser warning and errors, so the post garnered multiple spam flags.

Comment: @Stephie [User Ecnerwal appears to need the original video to answer the question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/122433/101749). Can a moderator link to the original video without looking like spam?

Comment: @user the problem is not so much how it was linked, the problem is opening Billibilli feels like opening a spam site due to popups. Moderators have no power over external sites :( I guess we can add the link back, but there is no guarantee that other users won't start flagging again.

Comment: Also, frankly, I don't see why you think Ecnerwal needs the video. The answer is already as complete as it can be without examining the pan physically.